# Wrong Url displayed after redirect to PageReference

Tags: visualforce, pagereference, platform-bug

Have some strange behavior of the URL that gets displayed in my browser after redirecting between pages with a shared controller.

**Reproducible Code**

```
public with sharing class FooController {

        //saves the quotes
    public PageReference toFoo1(){
        PageReference pr = Page.foo1;
        pr.setRedirect(false); 
        return pr;
    }

    public PageReference toFoo2(){
        PageReference pr = Page.foo2;
        pr.setRedirect(false); 
        return pr;
    }
}

<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="FooController">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:commandButton styleClass="button quote-btn" value="to foo2" action="{!toFoo2}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>

<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="FooController">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:commandButton styleClass="button quote-btn" value="to foo1" action="{!toFoo1}" />
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

After the first redirect, query params are dropped but the path does not change.  However, if I redirect again, then the URL is then updated to the previous page.

**Example:**

- Starting on `/apex/Foo1?bar=abc`...
- Click "To Foo2" button. URL now
  reads `/apex/Foo1`
- Click "To Foo1" button. URL now reads `/apex/Foo2`
- Click "To Foo2" button. URL now reads `/apex/Foo1`

## Update

Setting redirect to true is not an option as I do not want my viewstate to change.

Comment: I've seen this previously and found it very annoying, if you need the viewstate i think you're stuck. Personally I left it as is since I didn't believe end users would look very closely at the URLs. If you don't need a view state you can use `a` tags instead of commandbuttons.

Comment: you might just for fun try commandlink or outputlink to see if the behavior changes, i doubt it, but worth trying

Comment: true, refreshing the page causes odd behavior but I'm not sure how often uses will actually manually do so.  Also can lead to confusion if the client includes the url in a bug ticket.

Comment: FYI: commandlink has the same behavor and an outputlink doesn't preserve viewstate.

Answer (score 2):

```
 pr.setRedirect(false);
```

Instead of this. do this

```
pr.setRedirect(true);
```

Because `setRedirect(false)` don't refresh the view state and keep the value of controller variable. So update this.

Comment: I don't want the viewstate to change

Comment: @NSjonas I think you are stuck here because this is SF native behavior. Instead of view state you can try cookies if it is small data/